# Rails model named Statistics

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, naming-conventions

I have created following models:

```
# table - user_statistics
class UserStatistics < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :user_statistics

end
```

I have also put following rule into `inflections.rb`

```
inflect.uncountable %w( statistics )
```

But when i am trying to access the collection `user.user_statistics` I am getting an error:

> NameError: uninitialized constant User::UserStatistic

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: May be it is because of the class name `UserStatistics`.It should be singular `UserStatistic`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding `inflect.singular 'statistics', 'statistics'` into inflections.rb